# how to modify the ROO dropdown values?

Tags: spring-roo

I like to change the dropdown values which ROO automatically creates.  Please provide some guide lines how can I do it.  Right now the dropdown contains all the values from the domain class in a single line per row.

someting like this: dst1 District 6 1 admin 2011-04-02 12:00:00

I would like to get something like this: dst1 - District 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you should refer [to the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/org.springframework.roo.annotations/apidocs/org/springframework/roo/addon/web/mvc/controller/RooConversionService.html) and change your default registered convertors to meet your needs. Prior to Roo 1.1.1 all the convertors was registered right in controllers. Since 1.1.1 just look for `ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean` class in your ~.web package.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.  I am able to modify the dropdown values in 'ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean'.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using GWT as your front-end?  I'm going to assume you are.  If you're using SpringMVC, this answer obviously won't help much.

For the GWT Scaffold app generated by Spring Roo, look at the renderer class for the proxy of the entity in question.  For instance, if the entity being displayed in the drop-down is a `Foo` object, it will always be rendered in the web client by the `FooProxyRenderer` class from the `some.package.client.managed.ui` package.

The `public String render(FooProxy object)` method is what gets called to create the string that shows up in the drop-down box.  Modify that to return whatever representation of the entity you'd like.  Here's what a basic one looks like for a `CloudData` entity in one of my projects:

```
public String render(CloudDataProxy object) {
    if (object == null) {
        return "";
    }
    return object.getTitle() + " (" + object.getId() + ")";
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am using SpringMVC.